# How to delete temp files from subversion but retain the copy in my local folder?

Tags: svn, svnignore

When we moved to SVN, we just included anything and everything in our folders on subversion. I want to exclude all log files in a folder.

I am on Ubuntu.

```
thinkcode@myserver:~/Project1/Log/*.txt
```

All the .txt files are on subversion and these log files are created on a daily basis. I want to delete them off of subversion but retain them in my Log folder.

`svn propedit svn:ignore ./some_path` doesn't seem to do the trick. The new *.txt files are still showing as '?' when doing an `svn status`.I tried it on a new folder and I get `svn: 'c.txt' is not under version control`

Any leads are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, what do you mean *in Subversion*?

Let's clarify this:

- Subversion has a place where all files and versions are stored. This is the *repository*. You never see the actual directory structure of the repository, and you probably don't have read/write access there.
- You checkout the files from the repository to your local *working directory*. The *working directory* reflects a *particular version* of the various files and directories that are stored in your Subversion repository. However, you have access to them. If you make a change in one of these and commit them, you've updated the repository.

---

Okay, now that we have that cleared up, I'm going to make the assumption that the files you're talking about are located on your *local directory*, but not in the *source repository*. Is that correct?

In this case, the `svn:ignore` should be on the directory where the log files sit, and should have the value "*.txt". You can do it like this:

```
$svn propset svn:ignore "*.txt" .
```

Note the use of quotes around **.txt*. They're required in this case. What this will do is prevent new files in that directory from showing up if they match the glob pattern of your svn:ignore when you do a `svn status`. They will also not be added if you just say `svn add`:

```
$ svn add
```

However, if the files are already in the repository, the `svn:ignore` property will do nothing. If you want to remove the files from the repository, but keep them on your local disk, you can do this:

```
$ svn delete --keep-local (files to delete)
```

Comment: "Is that correct" - um, `svn status` gives `?` for these files. They are unversioned.

Comment: @mano Only for the *new* files, the old files are in svn (I guess, it's a pretty vague/confused question)

Comment: Thanks David, you answered both cases! I set the property on the folder (and files, tried both) which is (are) not in the repository and I still see the '?'? It is kinda annoying with few hundred text files in there. Won't the ignore property hide the '?' from even showing?

Comment: @ThinkCode. The `svn:ignore` goes on directories only. The files to ignore must be in _that_ directory and not a sub-directory.

Answer (score 1):

The svn status '?' means that an item is not under source control. svn status will list all files under the current directory which are under source control and have been modified or anything not under source control.

Therefore it seems if it's still in your local directory you've already achieved what you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

It takes two operations, delete and ignore.  first mark all the files for delete.  Then commit.  After that apply ignore, and make sure you apply it recursively.

Comment: But I don't want to delete the local copy. I want to delete only the subversion copy. If I do an svn delete *.txt, the local copy is gone which I don't want to happen.

Comment: your only option is to do an export to a different directory, delete the files, then copy the exported files back in.  Since, when you export them they don't retain the _svn metadata.